# MongoDB AddField Computed Sum of Child Array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iuol6M1ZSOf)

Lets say I have a simple object with on child array like this:

```
[
  {
    "BillingId": 1,
    "TotalBilling": 10,
    "Installments": [
      {
        "InstallmentId": "Inst01",
        "TotalPaid": 2
      },
      {
        "InstallmentId": "Inst02",
        "TotalPaid": 5
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I would like to run an Aggregation to $Addfied that would be the $sum of the 'TotalPaid' of the array Installments. And I would project the result adding another filed that would be the $subtract of the TotalBilling with the TotalInstallments.... would be like this:

```
[
  {
    "BillingId": 1,
    "TotalBilling": 10,
    "TotalInstallments": 7,
    "TotalBalanceDue": 3,
  }
]
```

I am wondering if I would to use Map and push the values of Installments or a Reduce or a Group???

[Here is a Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/iuol6M1ZSOf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an aggregation like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      "TotalInstallments": {
        $sum: "$Installments.TotalPaid"
      },
      "TotalBalanceDue": {
        $subtract: [
          "$TotalBilling",
          {
            $sum: "$Installments.TotalPaid"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: If installments is NULL or EMPTY, how to default to 0 (zero) ?

Comment: [$sum already handles non-numeric or non-existent values](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#non-numeric-or-non-existent-fields), and will default to 0.

Comment: Another problem... when the Total of Installments is string and not Decimal... Sum directly wont work... should O apply a MAP and user $toDecimal and then $sum ?

Comment: Just added another prop called Installments2 and did a MAP on Installments.Total and just $toDecimal. Worked fine! thanks.